# Creating a reference with CloudKit JS

Tags: javascript, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'm creating a record that should have a reference to another record.

I already created a record that has for RecordName `France` and for record type `Countries`. The record I now want to create looks like this:

```
var operations = container.publicCloudDatabase.newRecordsBatch(); // I'm normally creating many cities at once, newRecordsBatch() also works with only one record.  
operations.create({
    recordName: 'Paris'
    recordType: 'Cities',
    fields: {
        Country: {
            value: 'France'
        }
    }
});
operations.commit().then(function(response) {
    if(response.hasErrors) {
        console.log(response.errors[0]);
    }
});
```

In the CloudKit Dashboard I have set that `Cities` to have one reference to `Countries` using the field `Country`. However when running the code it returns `the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`.

I watched the WWDC video and the only thing Apple says about references in CloudKit JS is `use a Reference object`. I don't know what it is, I guess it's a JSON object but does someone know what are the key/values of this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Reference object is a dictionary with the following keys:

- recordName: The unique name used to identify the record within a zone. Required.
- zoneID: Dictionary that identifies a record zone in the database.
- action: The delete action for the reference object. `NONE` or `DELETE_SELF` or `VALIDATE`. Required.

Example of a good syntax for the `Country` field:

```
Country: {
    value: {
        recordName: 'France',
        action: 'DELETE_SELF'
    }
}
```

More info available in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/CloutKitWebServicesReference.pdf), pages 68-69.